# block / deny screenshot in framework7

Tags: android, html-framework-7

is there a way to block the screenshots of a view of an app developed in framework7? Or what other similar technology can I develop an app with this functionality? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will say that it is not possible to prevent it 100%, but you can use
1- The secure flag which blocks both normal screenshot and video capture

[You can check the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_SECURE)